# I don't understand the approach the solution manual is using towards answering part(b)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian

A test for the presence of a certain disease has probability
.20 of giving a false-positive reading (indicating that an
individual has the disease when this is not the case) and
probability .10 of giving a false-negative result. Suppose
that ten individuals are tested, five of whom have the
disease and five of whom do not. Let X 5 the number of
positive readings that result.
a. Does X have a binomial distribution? Explain your
reasoning.
b. What is the probability that exactly three of the ten
test results are positive?

[image]
The probabilities assigned here, for example, to the first case is not understandable since to me the prob(success) of having 0 detected out 5 affected people is supposed to be 0.1.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. Also, please use an informative title.

Comment: You may suggest the title. As for the pic, I asked this question before but hardly anyone was willing to understand without the picture and blaming the tediousness of the question.

Comment: In the first case there are $0$ false positives so $5$ true negatives, and $3$ true positives so $2$ false negatives.  Hence the ${5 \choose 0}(.2)^0(.8)^5$ and ${5 \choose 3}(.9)^3(.1)^2$ terms.  $D$ and $D'$ seem confused

Comment: @Henry: *Given* that $5$ are diseased and $5$ non-diseased, $D$ and $D'$ seems to be the number **marked** as diseased and non-diseased respectively.

Comment: @trueblueanil except that $D+D'=3$, the number of test positives in (b). It does not really matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*HINT*

See the chart below with the probabilities for the four quadrants.

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$Test +$\quad\quad$ Test -
Have disease $\quad\quad\quad\; 0.9a\quad\quad\quad 0.1b$

Don't have disease $\quad 0.2c\quad\quad\quad\ 0.8d$

a = true positive, b = false negative
c = false positive, d = true negative

You should be able to proceed from here

*Further Hint*

It is **given** that $5$ are diseased and $5$ non-diseased, but only $3$ have been marked as positive.

In the first case, all the $5$ diseased have been marked false negative, and from the $5$ non-diseased, $3$ have been marked false positive, and $2$ as true negative, so the first row should be

$\binom5 0 0.9^0*0.1^5 \times \binom5 3 *0.2^3*0.8^2$

**With this interpretation of D and D', the book answer seems awry !**

Comment: I can clearly see through it but the solution given in the manual seems to suggest otherwise

Comment: I have added a further hint, and I,  too, get a different formula from that of the book !